# Replace dot with comma of text which is not in DOM while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mutation-observers

I'm using a WordPress Theme and need to modify the output of a counter animation.
While the page is loading, there is an empty span like this:

`<span class="counter"></span>`

After the animation is finished, the span looks like this:

`<span class="counter">30.5</span>`

Since it is a german website the output needs to be with a comma instead of a dot, so it should look like this: 30,5
How can I achieve this?

Reading similar posts it looks like I need a WebKitMutationObserver (?) but I have no experience using it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you can not change the code that puts the text in there? Is there no event for the code that updates it?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. The client is using a theme with prebuilt widgets like the counter animation. If i modfify the JS files directly, the changes will disappear if the theme gets an update. Hard to explain. :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elCounter = $('#counter');

$('button').on('click', () => {
  $({progress: 0}).animate(
    {progress: 1000}, {
    duration: 30000,
    step: val =>  {
      elCounter.text((val / 10).toFixed(2));
    }}
  )
});

new MutationObserver(() => {
  const replacement = elCounter.text().replace('.', ',');
  
  if(elCounter.text() !== replacement){
    elCounter.text(replacement);
  }
})
.observe(elCounter[0], { childList: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button>Go progress</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `value.toLocaleString('en-de',{...})` will solve your purpose

```js
const counterElement = document.querySelector('.counter');
const value = parseFloat(counterElement.textContent);
const formattedValue = value.toLocaleString('en-de', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 1,
  maximumFractionDigits: 1
});
counterElement.textContent = formattedValue;
```

```html
<span class="counter">30.5</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not modify the inside of the span (it is empty while the page is loading, the value is stored somewhere else). That's why the mutation-observer is needed and the solution from @silent-mantra is working.